# Imprimir dashboard

Tags: php, html5, chart.js

Tengo un Dashboard con la plantilla de ValiAdmin con gráficos construidos por chart Js y una tabla de DataTable, necesito poder imprimir esa pagina y convertir en PDF pero los gráficos aparecen recortados, posteriormente corrijo los margenes se sigue viendo igual, alguien sabe como puedo hacer para que mis gráficos no desaparezcan?.
Imagen1(Dashboard en web)
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Imagen 2(Dashboard en para imprimir o convertir en pdf)
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Entiendo por las capturas que haces simplemente navegador > imprimir. Claro, no es tan fácil. Deberías usar alguna librería para generar un pdf. Ya sea de Front (jspdf+html2canvas) o de Back (DomPDF con php). Eso te daría mucho más  control sobre el pdf: escala, márgenes, tamaño del papel, etc.

Sólo con Chart.js... puedes buscar algún apaño, pero no creo que haya.